# User getting default Apache page instead of website - Safari/FF?

Tags: apache, macos, firefox, safari

I have someone complaining that www.archstl.org (a site I manage) loads fine from his Windows PC, but not on his Mac; and apparently he can't get it anywhere he takes his Mac, either...

I've heard of this happening to one other person, but I can't find an explanation. When they try loading it on their Mac using either Safari or FireFox, they get the default Apache page: "If you can see this, it means that the installation of the Apache web server software on this system was successful. You may now add content to this directory and replace this page."

I have had him ping www.archstl.org, and it always returns the proper IP address of our server (174.37.22.142), so I don't know what could be going wrong. It seems that our server is sending him the wrong page, plain and simple...?

Comment: You'll want to ask this on http://serverfault.com. It's not a programming question.

Comment: ... right, even though in this case it seems to be a client fault ;)

Comment: As a datapoint, I see this site fine from my Mac 10.5.7 using Safari 4. You'll want to mention on serverfault that you're using redirects to get to "http://www.archstl.org/" (note the final slash) and indicate how you're doing the redirects. Your problem probably is a failed redirect. That's a very common cause of getting the default Apache page.

Comment: @Nikolai.... :D The client is always right. heh....

Comment: Hmm... supposedly it might have something to do with the IPv6 address of www.archstl.org - any idea on how to correct that, either locally or via DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the dns entry for archstl.org included a self-referring ipv6 address (::), which caused Macs running Apache to go to localhost (ignoring the ipv4 address). Our data center removed the v6 address, and now all is well.